# How can I set Picasso placeholder scaleType?

Tags: android, picasso, scaletype

I've problem with placeholder images in Picasso. I use scaleType fitXY on one of my imageViews, but I don't really wanna scale my placeholder, is there a way that I can set different scaleType for my placeholder and another one for loaded image?

Answer (score 1):

Use Fresco lib open source library by Facebook, Using this library You can set different scale type to placeholder image and actual image use this link for reference http://frescolib.org/